# Spring: file isn't being downloaded when called in Controller, but is downloaded when in main method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a method like this:

It goes to a certain URL and downloads an `mp3` file from it. The data is saved in a file with the `path` name.

```
    public boolean downloadFile(String query, String path)  {
        try  {
            System.setProperty("http.agent", "Chrome");

            String link = generateUrl(query);
            System.out.println("Downloading from " + link);

            URL url = new URL(link);

            ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(
                    url.openStream());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
                    path);
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            System.out.println("Audio saved to file!");

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

when I simply call that method inside some `Test.java` main method:

```
downloadFile("stuff", "stuff.mp3");
```

it works fine: the file `stuff.mp3` appears in the root directory of the project.

However when I try to call that method from inside Spring controller (with query and filename passed as parameters), while it returns `200, "OK"`, the file never appears:

```
    @PostMapping("/api/file/new")
    @Transactional
    public String getFile(@RequestBody Map<String, String> body)  {
        String query = body.get("query");
        String filename = body.get("filename");

        if (query == null ||
                filename == null)  {
            return "Error!";
        }

        boolean success = speecher.downloadFile(query, filename);

        return success ? "OK" : "Something went wrong!";
    }
```

Why does this happen? How do I make it work (download the file) from inside the controller class?

**EDIT**:

Hardcoding the query and filename inside the controller method doesn't help (the file isn't downloaded):

```
boolean success = speecher.downloadFile("test", "test.mp3");
```

Comment: If you add a breakpoint just where you call `speecher::downloadFile` are the `query` and `filename` variables what they should be? Also is the stream/channel somehow closed implicitly? I'm not familiar with how `transferFrom` works.

Comment: @Dropout Yes they are. I also tried to make the call to `downloadFile` with hardcoded parameters when inside the controller's method, but same results (file not being downloaded). As for stream, I'll have to check, not sure about it myself.

Comment: Also avoid using `@RequestBody Map`. Instead, use a clean POJO, with the side benefit that you can apply `@Valid`.

Comment: @parsecer check it out if you can it might be an issue.. You can verify that by downloading the file twice.. Just call `downloadFile("stuff", "stuff1.mp3")` and then `downloadFile("stuff", "stuff2.mp3")` from the Test.class.. Do you get both files? I'm kinda just guessing here, I don't have an IDE open..

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in the right place? I'm not sure what path you are sending, but it's probably relative to where the main is started from and that might not be where you think it is when running your app.

Comment: I go with DCTID, I think the path is probably relative **on the server environment**. You know that this implementation doesn't download the file onto your local machine via browser but into the file system in the server environment?

Comment: @Dropout I tried hardcoding (see edits) + hardcoding unique name that wasn't used before. Same result ; (